Sending a post request to kubernetes web api along with json request in common lisp
I want to send a post method request to a kubernetes web api with json data request in common lisp.
The url is something like this :
http://qr-restservices-test1.xxx/v1/qual
The format for json data is below:
{
   "requestId":"12345",
   "houseNumber":"5555",
   "streetName":"Erling garden",
   "city":"PHOENIX",
   "state":"AZ",
   "unit":"",
   "floor":"",
   "building":"",
   "postalCode":"0000",
   "qualProcessType":"GGG",
   "network": "JINX",
   "SrcSystem": "BLUE"
}

what is the approach to write some lisp code for this, without using yason or cl-json?

You need an HTTP client, see Dexador: https://github.com/fukamachi/dexador/

I tried this in the listener as an example, but getting this error:
'(setq json-data '(("username" . "admin") ("password" . "secret")))
(("username" . "admin") ("password" . "secret"))
SOE 12 > (setq json-str (json:encode-json-to-string json-data))'
Error: Reader cannot find package JSON.
1 (continue) Create the JSON package.
2 Use another package instead of JSON.
3 Try finding package JSON again.
4 (abort) Return to debug level 0.

What is the problem with yason or cl-json?  Would shasht be OK, or do you want to write your own JSON serialization?

@Svante how can i write my own JSON serialization

What JSON library are you using? I recommend shasht or jzon. You can also generate the JSON string with string manipulation…
